# Sql server conversion issues from Binary Data type to Numeric data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, cdc

I am trying to persist values from one of the Sql server CDC table, which has column data type as "Binary(10)". I want to convert it into "Numeric" format and then convert it back to "Binary(10)".

For e.g.

```
declare @binary_data binary(10),@binary2 as binary(10)

select  @binary_data = 0x000000180003727C0006

Select Convert(int,0x00000018) as [PrecesionValue]
Select Convert(int,0x000) as [ScaleValue]

declare @Numeric as numeric(24,0) --Setting Numeric(PrecesionValue, ScaleValue)

Select @Numeric =Convert(numeric(24,0),@binary_data) 

Select @binary2 = Convert(binary(10),@Numeric) 

print @binary_data
print @Numeric
print @binary2
```

Output:

```
0x000000180003727C0006  //Initial binary data

393340                  //Converted Numeric value

0x0000180000017C000600  //Re-converted back to Binary value
```

If you see, the Re-convetred Binary value doesnt match the original value.
Can you please check where I am going wrong?

Comment: This definitely has to do with the way SQL Server does padding.  Binary gets padded on the right while other data types are padded/truncated on the left.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: This sounds like the [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Please try to describe, what you want to achieve, especially why you want to create a `numeric(24,0)`. If you just want to persist this value in a non-binary format, there are much better approaches (base64, hex-string, ...)

Comment: my requirement is to persist it in number format and then re-convert it back to binary for scanning purpose

Comment: My challenge is converting a column field stored in "Binary(10)" format to any number format BigInt/Decimal etc, since my application can not persist this Binary data type.

Comment: @rajcool111 Can you persist a String too. That was much easier...

Comment: @Shnugo Yes, I can persist in string, but its expensive in terms of space and indexing the records

Comment: Do you actually have to persist the round-trip conversion or do you just want to read the value as a number during a conversion?  You could then persist back the original binary and have a copy as a number for math or value usage.

Comment: @Sql Surfer I want to read te value as Number and persist. Then I want to use same value and convert it back to original binary and then use it for my processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "translate" a 10-byte binary to something *non-binary* you'd need a data type, which has at least 10 bytes storage space. But you should not rely on the bit pattern used by SQL Server to store a complex data type.

I want to suggest two approaches:

```
--this is your binary
declare @binary1 binary(10) 
set @binary1 = 0x000000180003727C0006;
select  @binary1; 

--XML will translate binaries to base64 implicitly
declare @string varchar(100);
set @string = (SELECT @binary1 AS [*] FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(100)');
select @string,LEN(@string);

--this is the approach to translate the base64 back to a binary
declare @binary2 binary(10);
set @binary2=CAST('<x>' + @string + '</x>' AS XML).value('.','varbinary(10)');
select @binary2; 

--the second approach is a GUID (16 byte)
declare @guid uniqueidentifier;
set @guid=@binary1
select @guid;

--a GUID is a simple chain of bytes, easy to cast
set @binary2=CAST(@guid AS VARBINARY(10));
select @binary2;
```

## UPDATE: one more idea came to my mind

There's a reason, why binary and string types are disussed [in one topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/string-and-binary-types?view=sql-server-2017). You can split your 10 byte binary in chunks and take them as separated numbers:

```
declare @binary1 binary(10) 
set @binary1 = 0x00000180003727C0006;
select  @binary1,SUBSTRING(@binary1,1,4) AS Byte0to3 
                ,SUBSTRING(@binary1,5,4) AS Byte4to8
                ,SUBSTRING(@binary1,10,2) AS Byte9to10;

declare @int1 INT, @int2 INT, @smallint smallint;
select  @int1 =     SUBSTRING(@binary1,1,4)  
       ,@int2 =     SUBSTRING(@binary1,5,4) 
       ,@smallint = SUBSTRING(@binary1,10,2);
select @int1,@int2,@smallint;

declare @binary2 binary(10);
set @binary2 = CAST(@int1 AS binary(4)) + CAST(@int2 AS binary(4)) + CAST(@smallint AS binary(2));
select @binary2;
```

Comment: thanks @Shnugo for your inputs. I see you have provided good options to store these values in guid, base64 or string. But, my requirement is to store them in Number format and then reconvert it into original Binary as needed. Not sure, if this will work in my use case.

Comment: @rajcool111 the Update provides an approach to store your value in several numbers.

Comment: There is a mistake in the above.   
SUBSTRING(@binary1,10,2) AS Byte9to10; should be 
SUBSTRING(@binary1,9,2) AS Byte0to9;  

You did not detect it because your input test value has no bits set that high